# Is possible to add a folder and its content as submodule in a repository that already have a folder with the same name?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose that I have two repositories structured like this.

```
Repo1/
├─src/
│ ├─folder1/
│ │ ├─file-a
│ │ └─file-b
│ ├─folder2/
│ │ ├─file-c
│ │ └─file-d
│ └─folder3/
│   ├─file-e
│   └─file-f
└─ README.md

Repo2/
├─src/
│ ├─folder1/
│ │ ├─file-g
│ │ └─file-h
│ ├─folder2/
│ │ ├─file-i
│ │ └─file-j
│ └─folder3/
│   ├─file-k
│   └─file-l
└─ README.md
```

What I want is to "merge" the contents of `src/` of the two repositories into Repo2 and obtain the following structure (file prefixed with "*" are from Repo1).

```
Repo2/
├─src/
│ ├─folder1/
│ │ ├─*file-a
│ │ ├─*file-b
│ │ ├─file-g
│ │ └─file-h
│ ├─folder2/
│ │ ├─*file-c
│ │ ├─*file-d
│ │ ├─file-i
│ │ └─file-j
│ └─folder3/
│   ├─*file-e
│   ├─*file-f
│   ├─file-k
│   └─file-l
└─ README.md
```

Of course, I'm sure that there are no files with the same name on the same path. Also, when working on Repo2 I don't need to make changes to files of Repo1.

---

Note that the files in Repo1 are a dependency for code in files in Repo2. Unfortunately, I cannot change the structure of the project. The workaround would be to either duplicate the code and lose any reference to the first repository or to have code that doesn't work but with instructions in the README on how to copy from the first repository.

Comment: I think you should use command line and copy files from repo1 to repo2 using cp -rl source destination then make a commit to repo2

Comment: @AbhaySehgal In this way any update made on Repo1 will not be available on Repo2.

Comment: Okay, so you want repo1 changes in repo2 ?

Comment: You can add another remote in repo2 pointing to repo1 and when you push in repo1, just take a pull in repo2 from repo1

Comment: @AbhaySehgal, In this case, I should have branches dedicated to Repo1 and branches dedicated to Repo2, and this is acceptable. However, my working tree would be full of changes that I don't need. With a lot of files, it will be unsustainable.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in comment. You can use command line ( terminal in case of macOs and Linux ) to copy files from repo1 src to repo2 src using below command

```
cp -rl source destination
```

Replace source with repo1 src folder path and destination with repo2 src path.

Now repo2 contains repo1 files as well so you can commit it.

Comment: As I've mentioned in comment, this is not what I want: the code would be duplicated and updates in Repo1 would not be available in Repo2.